# ie8 ignoring styles on WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

On XP, IE8  site http://rweberjewelry.com/ is ignoring styles. Here's a video http://www.screenr.com/AeMH. It works fine on Win7 IE9. This started when I updated to WP 3.5.2 and latest theme version.

Problems - images not showing, fonts are huge, page container does not fill page, and just overall ignoring of most styles!

Theme designer says it renders well on their browser emulator and "..there is something else in play either on your network or computer. If the browser is getting pushed into compatibility mode for some reason or something similar."

I had a friend check her computer and it is having the same problem. 
I read a suggestion to add the following but it didn't help:
     meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"

I checked:
IE>tools>compatibility mode> website is not listed and "display all websites in compatibility mode" is not checked and ripped paper icon is not showing next to the URL so I don't think it is in compatibility mode.

Much thanks for any ideas.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/css/base.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/css/slideshow.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/css/shortcodes.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/js/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/js/projekktor/theme/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<!-- plugin and theme output with wp_head() -->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='testimonials-widget-css'  href='http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/plugins/testimonials-widget/testimonials-widget.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='avia-woocommerce-css-css'  href='http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/config-woocommerce/woocommerce-mod.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />

<!-- custom styles set at your backend-->
<style type='text/css' id='dynamic-styles'> 
        <!----a ton of stuff deleted  - too long ----->
</style>

<!-- google webfont font replacement -->
<link id="google_webfont_1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rweberjewelry.com/wp-content/themes/propulsion/css/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

</head>
```

Comment: SO requires that code be shown. Post the HEAD contents from IE.

Comment: HEAD is quite long... will try in sections even with much deleted

Comment: ah well thanks anyway... it's just too long

Comment: All I'm really looking for are the CSS links and meta tags.

Comment: ok - thank you for your patience. I added it above.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some HTML issues that IE8 isn't handling quite as gracefully as the other browsers. Some of the worst offenses are apostrophes in HTML attributes, which prematurely end the attribute.

[W3C validator results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://rweberjewelry.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: I'm not too worried about "graceful" on my ie8 I am not seeing images. Is your view better than this, please?
 http://www.screenr.com/AeMH